# Is it possible to get bigrams from significant_terms aggregation in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am wondering if it possible to get bigrams from significant_terms aggregation in Elasticsearch.

I am querying an index with 200 Million sentences which have been indexed using an additional bigram analyzer. So the bigrams are indexed. However, when I run a significant_terms aggregation, I only get unigrams from ES.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Are you running the aggregation against the bigram or the unigram field?

Comment: The bigrams are stored in the index and not in the _source fields. So I am running the aggregation against the field that got indexed using the bigram analyzer.

Comment: Aggregation does not at all require the field to be in `_source`. It requires it to either be in doc values (which analyzed strings, like bigrams, are not) or in the inverted index. Just specify the multi-field as aggregated field.